# How does jquery's bower.json file point to a folder not included in git?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bower

I am trying to understand how bower works..

If you look at jquery's github repo https://github.com/jquery/jquery you will see that the `bower.json` file points to `dist/jquery.js`.  However, the repo does not include this folder on github, because the `/dist` folder is a product of the build step that is not checked into git (it is included in `.gitignore`).

So I am at a loss for how bower finds the `dist/jquery.js` file when it is not included in the git repo??

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other points that should lead you on your way:

- `Gruntfile.js` has a `build` task that outputs the built file to `dist/jquery.js` (see also `build/tasks/build.js`).
- `package.json` has a dependency on [`grunt-bowercopy`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-bowercopy).

Related: [Managing Bower components with Grunt](http://simonsmith.io/managing-bower-components-with-grunt/)

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused.  I was under the assumption the bower registry points to a specific git repo and/or file.  Is bower smart enough to do the grunt build step automatically before it gets the final `dist/jquery.js` file on its own?

Comment: bower points to a tag in the repo, rather than a branch. Have a look at the latest tag, for instance: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

As @cbuckley said, the trick is that Bower will checkout from Git a tagged version instead of the master head. If you have a look at Jquery, the 2.1.1 tagged version has a jquery.js in dist/